# How do i make a password and username in trinket python?

Tags: python, passwords, filenames

i have tried

def main():
while True:
UserName = input ("Enter Username: ")
PassWord = input ("Enter Password: ")

```
    if UserName == Bob and PassWord == rainbow123:
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("Login successful!")
        logged()

    else:
    print ("Password did not match!")
```

def logged():
time.sleep(1)
print ("Welcome to ----")

main()

but i dont know why it wont work

somebody plz help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't defined the username and password as a string in the 'if' statement.

```
import time

def main(): 
    while True: 
        UserName = input("Enter Username: ") 
        PassWord = input("Enter Password: ")

        if UserName == "Bob" and PassWord == "rainbow123":
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Login successful!")
            logged()

        else:
            print("Password did not match!")
def logged(): 
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("Welcome to ----")
main()
```

Comment: k thx so is this the correct code?

Comment: It works for what your requested.